# Confusion regarding variable assignment and allocation

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment

Below is the Test program for the concept of inheritance.
If I am running this program then the o/p is "Im A's method - 1" and if I remove the comment then the output is "Im b's method - 2".

```
   class A {

        public void test(int x){
            System.out.println("Im A's method - 1");
        }

        public void test(Integer x){
            System.out.println("Im A's method - 2");
        }
   }

   class B extends A{
        public void test(Integer x){
            System.out.println("Im b's method - 1");
        }


        // public void test(int x){
        //     System.out.println("Im b's method - 2");
        // }
        // 
   }

   public class Test {
        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A a=new B();
            a.test(2);
        }
   }
```

---

**Question:**

As per my knowledge it should not extend to class A. Correct me please !!!

Comment: @downvoter please drop a comment !! :)

Comment: You should read about Java polymorfism and inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic case of `dynamic binding` in Java.So first after reading this comment you should read a little about [**this**](http://javarevisited.blogspot.ro/2012/03/what-is-static-and-dynamic-binding-in.html)

Second of all.It's showing **Im A's method - 1** because look at at your `main`,you are saying `A value = new B()` you are saying something like I have an automobile and I want it to be a car.

Furthermore you are calling a method on a value of type `int` not `Integer` so it goes calling the method that requires an `int` in `B`'s class.

Because you have no such method it goes ahead and searches for it in the superclass.

**PS:** If you intend on continuing learning java and working in java this is one of the questions you will get a lot at interviews

Comment: @NoobEditor how do you add that highlight to a word?

Comment: use ` above TAB key in standard keyboard...also in formatting help while answering :)

Comment: Thank you a lot for this.You don't know how many times I was faced with this edit and didn't know how other people did it

Comment: you are welcome...you can simply click the grey *edit* link in below every answer and check all the formatting characters by yourself!! ;)

Comment: after your first answer I did click on the edit and couldn't believe my eyes

Answer (score 2):

When you call a method on your `a` variable, it'll call the version of the method defined in the `B` class if there is one; otherwise it'll call the version inherited from `A`.

You're calling `test` with the literal number 2, which is an `int`, not an `Integer`.  So the method being called is `test(int)`, not `test(Integer)`.  Since `B` doesn't define a `test(int)` method, it calls the one from `A`.

If `A` didn't have a `test(int)` method either, then the compiler would convert the `int` to an `Integer` (this is called "autoboxing") and look for an available `test(Integer)` method.  In that case, you'd get the one from `B`.  But when you pass an `int`, any available `test(int)` method (even an inherited one) is preferred over a `test(Integer)` method.

Answer (score 1):

**Overriding is resolved at run-time and hence, it will always look after the object which is of B class in your case.**

```
A a = new B();
```

Hence, once you override the test() method and run the main method, B's method will be called otherwise A's method will be called.

Answer (score 1):

See when you do

```
A a = new B();
```

All the methods in `B` that override the methods of `A` will be accessible plus the ones in `A` which arent overridded by `B` will be accessible.

so

```
a.test(1); will print "Im A's method - 1"

a.test(new Integer(1)); will print "Im B's method - 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

> what does this imply? does a always point to methods in class B or it means something else?

Yes. When you write

```
A a=new B();
```

Now when you call methods on `a`, overridden implementations from class `B` calls.

Comment: so if i call a method from `a`. it would first be looked in `class B` and if not found there then it would be looked in `class A` only because i did `A a=new B();`??

Comment: No need to look up. You just wrote `A a = new B()`. So JVM have enough information to call which method.